# Display full file name in vifm

Tags: file-manager, vifm

I have two almost identical file names in vifm panel like:

```
LongFileNameIn|Panel
LongFileNameIn|ThisPanel
```

where `|` is a border of a panel. I wonder if there is a way to display file full name in some status line or other view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If terminal width is enough, you can sacrifice other information in status line and display only file name there by changing [`'statusline'`](http://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm-%27statusline%27) option:

```
set statusline=%t
```

You could also switch to single pane mode when working with such files using [`:only`](http://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm-%3Aonly) command.

If whole width isn't enough and this is rare case, name could be `echo`ed on the status bar at request (easy to map to some shortcut):

```
:echo expand('%"c')
```

As many elements are displayed one per line, there is actually no universal way of displaying very long file names that do not fit into screen.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, similar to `:only`, is `:split` or key map `c-w/s`. It will display your panels split horizontally.